# google v8 New failed in linux shared library raise "segment error"

Tags: c++, linux, v8

I have a problem using Google V8 in linux. If I create a V8 instance in my shared library, I get a segfault. The same code works fine in a Windows DLL and in a linux executable.

My code:

```
extern "C" void InitV8ExtensionInterFace(){
    v8::V8::InitializeICU();
    v8::V8::Initialize();
    v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::New(); **//error occur** 
    threadfunc(argc, args);
}
```

`gdb` stack trace:

```
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff3cb86d5 in v8::internal::Builtins::SetUp (this=0x7fffffffb9e0, isolate=0x235abb0, create_heap_objects=false) at ../src/builtins.cc:1567
#2  0x00007ffff3e271cf in v8::internal::Isolate::Init (this=0x235abb0, des=0x0) at ../src/isolate.cc:2115
#3  0x00007ffff3c96049 in v8::Isolate::New (params=...) at ../src/api.cc:6861
#4  0x00007ffff3b78d40 in InitV8ExtensionInterFace () at ../Framework/ExPublic.cpp:107
#5  0x00000000004729db in myTest1 () at arangod/RestServer/arangod.cpp:106
#6  0x0000000000472a50 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe118) at arangod/RestServer/arangod.cpp:126
```

It appears that in the V8 function `void Builtins::SetUp(Isolate* isolate, bool create_heap_objects)`, the array `functions` is empty. If I initialize `v8::Platform`, the error will occur in code `V8::InitializePlatform(platform)`:

```
extern "C" void InitV8ExtensionInterFace(){
    v8::V8::InitializeICU();
    v8::Platform* platform = v8::platform::CreateDefaultPlatform();
    v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform); **//error occur** 
    v8::V8::Initialize();
    v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::New(); 
    threadfunc(argc, args);
}
```

`gdb` stack trace:

```
 1: V8_Fatal
 2: v8::internal::V8::InitializePlatform(v8::Platform*)
 3: InitV8ExtensionInterFace
 4: 0x4aab60
 5: 0x4aacf1
 6: 0x5f4532
 7: 0x47c32b
 8: 0x474498
 9: 0x472ae1
10: __libc_start_main
11: 0x4726f9

Thread 1 received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff66595e5 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007ffff66595e5 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff665adc5 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007fffc6e7d9c9 in v8::base::OS::Abort () at ../src/base/platform/platform-posix.cc:233
#3  0x00007fffc6e7b586 in V8_Fatal (file=0x7fffc703f535 "../src/v8.cc", line=107, format=0x7fffc6ffe77a "Check failed: %s.") at ../src/base/logging.cc:116
#4  0x00007fffc6cbd909 in v8::internal::V8::InitializePlatform (platform=0x267d840) at ../src/v8.cc:107
#5  0x00007fffc690bc8b in InitV8ExtensionInterFace () at ../Framework/ExPublic.cpp:98
#6  0x00000000004aab60 in myTest () at arangod/V8Server/ApplicationV8.cpp:1068
#7  0x00000000004aacf1 in triagens::arango::ApplicationV8::prepare2 (this=0x2378310) at arangod/V8Server/ApplicationV8.cpp:1093
#8  0x00000000005f4532 in triagens::rest::ApplicationServer::prepare2 (this=0x2377000) at arangod/ApplicationServer/ApplicationServer.cpp:525
#9  0x000000000047c32b in triagens::arango::ArangoServer::startupServer (this=0x2375330) at arangod/RestServer/ArangoServer.cpp:1009
#10 0x0000000000474498 in triagens::rest::AnyServer::start (this=0x2375330) at arangod/Rest/AnyServer.cpp:347
#11 0x0000000000472ae1 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe118) at arangod/RestServer/arangod.cpp:139
```

I get "4.3.61" at runtime with `v8::V8::GetVersion`.

This problem has troubled me for several days, Very much hope that someone will give me help, thank you.

Comment: @isanae version at runtime is "4.3.61", via function `v8::V8::GetVersion`

Comment: if i don't initialize Platform the error occur in the function `v8::Isolate::New`. GDB information: #0 0x0000000000000000 in ?? () #1 0x00007ffff3cb86d5 in v8::internal::Builtins::SetUp (this=0x7fffffffb9e0, isolate=0x235abb0, create_heap_objects=false) at ../src/builtins.cc:1567 #2 0x00007ffff3e271cf in v8::internal::Isolate::Init (this=0x235abb0, des=0x0) at ../src/isolate.cc:2115 #3 0x00007ffff3c96049 in v8::Isolate::New (params=...) at ../src/api.cc:6861 #4 0x00007ffff3b78d40 in InitV8ExtensionInterFace () at ../Framework/ExPublic.cpp:107 #5 0x00000000004729db in myTest1 () at arangod/Rest

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a call to [`V8::InitializeExternalStartupData()`](http://v8.paulfryzel.com/docs/master/classv8_1_1_v8.html#a943c1dbe5b91deb69efdeeaef26c46c7), see the [Get Started](https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started) tutorials.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Initialize V8.
    V8::InitializeICU();
    V8::InitializeExternalStartupData(argv[0]);
    Platform* platform = platform::CreateDefaultPlatform();
    V8::InitializePlatform(platform);
    V8::Initialize();

    // ...
}
```

You will need to copy `natives_blob.bin` and `snapshot_blob.bin` alongside your executable. They should be somewhere with the V8 binaries.

---

Looking at your edits with a better stack trace, you're running into two very different problems. Your first crash (the empty `functions` array) is because you're not calling `CreateDefaultPlatform()`, which is mandatory.

The second crash is inside `InitializePlatform()` on this line:

```
void V8::InitializePlatform(v8::Platform* platform) {
    CHECK(!platform_);     // <- here
    CHECK(platform);
    platform_ = platform;
}
```

This check is to make sure the default platform is only created once. It appears that you're calling `InitializePlatform()` twice. You can try putting a breakpoint in it to figure out where it gets called from.

Comment: Hi, I built v8 myself, and the v8 comes Arangodb here, the version is "4.3.61". And there is no function named "v8::InitializeExternalStartupData".

Comment: @cai.li Can you try fixing your gdb install to get a better backtrace? 4.3 is more than a year old, but I'll try to figure out something, Don't lose hope.

Comment: @cai.li I've dug up my old code, it's doing the same thing you do in the second snippet with `CreateDefaultPlatform()`. Are you sure you're compiling against the same version as the `.so`? Can you check `v8::internal::Version` and make sure you get the right version at runtime?